# How to specify full namespace for factory.create()

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm using [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) to make SOAP requests to a third-party API.

```
import suds.client
client = suds.client.Client(WSDL_URL, location=SERVICE_URL)
```

When I try to create an object for a particular type defined by the WSDL (say `TheObject`):

```
obj = client.factory.create('TheObject')
```

I'm getting an error about it not existing:

```
(TheObject) not-found
path: "TheObject", not-found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "suds_test.py", line 67, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "suds_test.py", line 51, in main
    obj = client.factory.create('TheObject'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 234, in create
    raise TypeNotFound(name)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'TheObject'
```

So I print the [list of available suds factory types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678039/369450) with `print(client)`:

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( OrderService ) tns="http://api.example.com/services/"
   Prefixes (2)
      ns0 = "http://api.example.com/contracts/stuff"
      ns1 = "http://api.example.com/services/"
   Ports (2):
      (OrderServiceSoap)
         Methods (123):
            ... Not really relevant
         Types (123):
            SomeType
            SomeType2
            ns0:AnotherType
            ns0:AnotherType2
            ns0:TheObject
            ...
```

So it appears that `ns1` is the default namespace, and `ns0` is the namespace I want to use for `TheObject`. If I prefix it with the namespace alias it works.

```
obj = client.factory.create('ns0:TheObject')
```

I would prefer not to have to remember to use `ns0` in this particular case because its vary arbitrary. I looked up the docs for [`Factory.create()`](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.client.Factory-class.html#create) but it only accepts a single argument *name* with no additional arguments for namespace URL or anything.

Is there a way to dynamically determine the namespace for `TheObject`? Or is it possible to specify the whole URL for `ns0` instead of just the namespace alias? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And it should have been painfully obvious to me that it is a standard XML namespace, and it's clearly indicated in the [documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FACTORY) (which I missed).

To specify the namespace by URL you simply prefix the name with the namespace URL wrapped in `{}` (curly braces):

```
obj = client.factory.create('{http://api.example.com/contracts/stuff}TheObject')
```